# Sharing Databases with Another person

Tags: mysql

I am currently working on a class project with another person on databases and am using MySQL workbench. How can they access the database and tables that are on a localhost?

Comment: Honestly I would suggest he works on his own development environment with his own database.

Comment: Agree - there's a lot to this. You need MySQL configured to listen to TCP bound to a net interface, your firewall has to be open to your friend's host on port 3306, and you need to create a database user with a password accessible from that host (mysql security is user+password+connecting IP/hostname) There are a lot of requirements to do it securely.

Comment: They can use a vpn and expose the db port to local network :P

Answer (score 0):

Open port 3306 on your computer or the server where mysql runs on or another port if this is the case.

It is best to create a separate user for this other person and give him certain permisions, more info about that here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/access-control.html

Or you could install something on your computer or the server where mysql runs on like phpmyadmin (this allows you to use the database from within a web application) with a web server like apache. If you don't know how to do these things and you are on windows I recommend reading a bit about XAMP or WAMP.

I hope this helped, good luck!